# Check if variableName is True or not

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How does it work ? What does the if condition do ?

```
function variableName(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        if (!('a' <= name[i] && name[i] <= 'z' ||
            'A' <= name[i] && name[i] <= 'Z' ||
            '1' <= name[i] && name[i] <= '9' ||
            name[i] === '_')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if ('0' <= name[0] && name[0] <= '9') {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I understand that he check the validation of the variable name , but I didn't understand what 'a' 'z' || 'A' 'Z' || refere to ?!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: looks like you are trying to determine whether the characters in a variable called name are a-zA-Z0-9 ~ if so, a regex would be a far simpler test.

Comment: You should use regex: `/^([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$/.test(name)`

Answer (score 1):

When comparing strings javascript compares their character code, so a check like `'a' <= name[i] && name[i] <= 'z'` just checks if the character code for `name[i]` is between those of 'a' and 'z'

Effectively it just checks if the character is between a and z (both inclusive) i.e. it just checks if it's a lower case alphabet.

And the rest is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The first IF condition ensures that the variable name should contain either lower case alphabets OR upper case alphabets OR numericals between 1 to 9 OR underscore `_`. If either of these fail then it returns `false`.

Next, it also checks that first letter of the variable name is not a numerical between 0 to 9.

The ultimate condition to return `true` from this method is that the variable name should contain alphanumeric characters only (a-zA_Z1-9), and that the first letter shouldn't be a numerical.